# Border-radius 50% creating an unintended border

Tags: html, css, image, border

In HTML and CSS, I need to create perfect circle img elements, where the src is set to various logos. The issue arises when I apply a 50% border-radius,parts of each logo get blocked out circularly as if there were a thick border set.

In the provided image, it can be seen I've set the following properties: nothing works.

```
border-style: none;
border-width: 0;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0;
overflow: visible;
```

(thought that last one would work for sure)

[code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5tJd.png)

Answer (score -1):

@hashkeeper You have a box-shadow set on each image on line, which put a weird bottom border on each image:

[image]

If you remove the line 59, you will no longer have the weird bottom grey border on each image.